# Setting RequestBody properly of MockHttpServletRequestBuilder

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I am simply trying to test a Spring controller method using a `MockHttpServletRequestBuilder`. The signature of the controller method looks like this:

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/assignTeamsToUsers", method = RequestMethod.POST)
 public @ResponseBody String assignUsersToTeams(Model model, @RequestBody MultiValueMap<String, String> ids).
```

In my test case I have:

```
MockMvc mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(applicationContext).build();
MockHttpServletRequestBuilder request = createRequest(uri, method);

//set up request object...Not sure how??
//My current attempt:
     String body = "userIds[]=0&teamIds[]=0";
     request.content(body);
     request.accept(MediaType.ALL);
     request.contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED);

ResultActions resultActions = mockMvc.perform(request);
```

EDIT: Showing createRequest. `method` = "POST"

```
private MockHttpServletRequestBuilder createRequest (String uri, String method) {
    MockHttpServletRequestBuilder builder = null;

    if("GET".equalsIgnoreCase(method))
        builder = MockMvcRequestBuilders.get(uri);
    else if("POST".equalsIgnoreCase(method))
        builder = MockMvcRequestBuilders.post(uri);
    else
        Assert.fail("Unsupported method!");

    //We always create requests for user Manager
    builder.header("securityRole", Role.Manager.getDisplayName());

    return builder;

}
```

I know the uri and method are correct. My problem is I am getting a **415** error code from Spring. Basically, I do not know how to set up the `request` object to have the appropriate `@RequestBody` for the `MultiValueMap`. I have tried alot of variations of setting request.content, setting the request.accept, request.contentType, request.characterEncoding, and still every time I get a 415 error.

If it is any help, I can successfully Post to this endpoint using the web interface, and here is what the request looks like in chrome:

[image]

Comment: Where are you using the `request`?

Comment: In my test case... I am not sure if I understand your question. I updated my question though to show more of the test code.

Comment: Ok, so I want to see  what `createRequest` does? What is `method`?

Comment: The `MockHttpServletRequestBuilder` class has a number of chaining methods which help you build up your request. Use `accept(..)` to set up your `Accept` headers, use `content(..)` to provide the request body content, etc.

Comment: Yeah...I've messed around with those quite a bit, I'll keep looking into it though. I have updated my question with my most recent attempt. Thanks for your help btw.

Comment: Let's also see your MVC configuration for your controllers. What you are doing seems fine to me.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I got it working. Thanks for your effort to help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I ended up solving this by doing the following:

```
MockHttpServletRequestBuilder request = MockMvcRequestBuilders.post("whatever url");
request.contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED);

//set key value pairs
//also the keys do not have to be unique, two keys of the same value will both get added 
request.param("key", "value");

MockMvc mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(applicationContext).build();
ResultActions resultActions = mockMvc.perform(request);
// make sure response is valid
```

Hope this can lead someone else in the right direction.
Thanks

Comment: Do you need to use param? or can you use content? I've tried using content for the request body but it's null when I print it out. I'm using APPLICATION JSON instead.